# Need link inside tab

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

i am trying to have a hyperlink inside a tab.
Here is the code:

```
Ext.onReady(function () {
Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel', {
    items: [{
        title: 'xyz',
    }, {
        title: 'abc',
    }],
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
Ext.create("Ext.Component", {
   renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
   autoEl: {
       style : 'margin: 100px 0 0 60px;color:red;margin-top: 40px;',
       html: "x1y1z1",
       href: "#",
       tag: "a"
    }
  });
});
```

i dont have any idea how to put the code of this link inside tab. please help.
here is the snapshot[image]

Right now hyperlink is outside the xyz tab.i want to put it inside.

Comment: You want a link in the tab title?

Comment: Not in the tab title, but title should be "xyz". but the link should be in the content of xyz.such that if i click on "abc",link should not be visible.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel', {
    items: [{
        title: 'xyz',
        items: [
          {
            xtype: 'box',
            autoEl: {
             style : 'margin: 100px 0 0 60px;color:red;margin-top: 40px;',
             html: "x1y1z1",
             href: "#",
             tag: "a"
            }
          }
        ]
    }, {
        title: 'abc',
    }],
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't actually make those tabs do anything, just added text to them. Then another ref on the body.

Check this out: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/tabs/tabs.js

Hope it was helpful.